# websql performance, can we shard tables

Tags: sqlite, sharding, web-sql

I am using websql to store data in a phonegap application. One of table have a lot of data say from 2000 to 10000 rows. So when I read from this table, which is just a simple select statement it is very slow. I then debug and found that as the size of table increases the performance deceases exponentially. I read somewhere that to get performance you have to divide table into smaller chunks, is that possible how?

Comment: WebSQL is deprecated and might not be supported in future browsers. Just warning you ( http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/ )

Comment: Have you tried creating indexes on your tables? That might speed-up SELECT queries.

Comment: Yes indexed column..still no performance tuning.

Comment: SQLite easily supports billions of rows. Show the actual query that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to look for something to group the rows by and consider breaking into separate tables based on some common category - instead of a shared table for everything.

I would also consider fine tuning the queries to make sure they are optimal for the given table.

Make sure you're not just running a simple Select query without a where clause to limit the result set.

Comment: I can not have multiple tables, that is an limitation for me. and I only read 10 results using limit variable. Any more suggestion?